# laravel global countries list avaiable on any page

Tags: php, laravel

How do I store data like a country list to be global across the site. So if I land on a specific page and it could be any page out of the site; I need to have a country list on that page, so how is this done. Could you please leave me an example of code.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views you can do it in a database table or just a hard coded array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **View Composers** and you can do it like below in the boot method. For more details check here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Service providers are probably what you're after. For example, my app uses the same list of US states in various places, so in my `AppServiceProvider::boot()` I have:

```php
    $this->app->bind('us-states', function () {
        return cache()->rememberForever(
            State::CACHE_KEY_US,
            function () {
                return State::US()->orderBy('name')->get();
            }
        );
    });
```

In my case this calls the `scopeUS()` method on the `State` model, and gets the result ordered by name. This kind of data rarely changes, so it's wrapped in a cache()->rememberForever() call, but that's not strictly necessary.

Then in my app, I have calls like `$states = app('us-states')`. As a previous answer pointed out you could also use `View::share('us-states',app('us-states'))` to make that collection available globally to your views.